# To make reversal study

Tags: pine-script

I' am looking to input a green arrow on the chart when a stock closes in the negative zone for 5 consecutive days and is followed by positive candle today. I used the following code

```
concurrentloser = (close[3] < close[4]) and (close[2] < close[3] and (close[1] < close[2]))

long = concurrentloser and (close > close[1])

strategy.entry ("Buy", strategy.long, 100, when = long)
```

but something is wrong it seems.

Can somebody help ?

Answer (score 0):

```
loser = close < close[1]
winner = not loser
loserValue = loser ? 1 : 0
long = sum(loserValue,5)[1] == 5 and winner
plotshape(long,style=shape.circle,color=color.green,size=size.small)
```

You can think of defining true and false conditions for the present bar only then use sum or the history-referencing operator to use it on previous values. Basically we define winner and loser (I considered 0 net change a winner but that's up to you), then set a loserValue. Basically this converts the true or false to a 1 or 0. Then to see if you have 5 consecutive losers, you can take the sum for 5 days, `sum(loserValue,5)`. Which will be five after 5 days of loss. Then use the history-referencing operator `[1]` as we want a winner value for today, and the five consecutive losses ending the previous day.

If the sum throws you off just do a simple
`long = winner and loser[1] and loser[2] and loser[3] and loser[4] and loser[5]`.